# how to change MPU9150 sensitivity?

Tags: c, mpu

I want to know what sensitivity I am working with on an mpu 9150  (+ Raspberry PI).

[this is the library I am using: linux-mpu9150](https://github.com/mrbichel/linux-mpu9150)

[mpu 9150 page](https://www.invensense.com/products/motion-tracking/9-axis/mpu-9150/)

I want the accelerometer to have more sensitivity(so I must set it to 2+/-g ?!?).

When I count the steps, there aren't enough...I take 10 steps, I count 3-5 steps with matlab (with `peakfinds` or counting zero crossing)

Example:

[image]

Accelerometer at my foot, or at my shin (make similar output)

Comment: Can you please show the current code and output and desired output?

Comment: What I do in matlab is something like this: https://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/mobilesensor/examples/counting-steps-by-capturing-acceleration-data-from-your-android-device.html?prodcode=ML   The desired output is will clearly distinguished peaks in the output (for better working with the peakfind algorithm)  What is the output with 10steps is this http://i.imgur.com/N4zfCNj.png   and the output from IMU

Comment: 9:19:16 -1440 16072 2292
9:19:17 -1380 15510 4050
9:19:18 212 17602 3040
9:19:19 -2048 19548 -3334
9:19:20 -4478 24740 21200
.. From IMU i can write out to the file 1 value of X,Y,Z in 1sec....maybe this is my problem? I doesnt have for example. in 1sec 10 value of X,Y,Z acceleration ?

Comment: Better edit the question, it's incomprehensible that way, also the links are broken.

Comment: Real question is...how (which file,where) to change the accelerometer sensitivity in library? https://github.com/mrbichel/linux-mpu9150

Answer (score 0):

The github link you posted contains a calibration section, they suggest using `imucal` here:

https://github.com/mrbichel/linux-mpu9150/blob/master/README.md

Good luck.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I have already calibrated accelerometer/magnetometer. This effect  calibrated XYZ values from the sensor,but I working with RAW X,Y,Z values. I figured out how to read from register, and I can now confirm with sensitivity in tune. (is +/- 2g). Now I have problem, when I walking with imu what is at my feet, I only can find peaks pretty good,when I walking very slowly , tempo: 1 step / 1,5-2 secund .  When I walk in normal tempo, I can find only for example. 40 step I find with my algorithm only 13 step. have anybody some advice how can I increment measurement ?